# Is there a way to break line in comment?

Tags: discussion

[image]

I was trying to put point-form in the comment section but it doesn't look very good, is there a way to put a line break in the comment section?

Comment: Just as a side note, the Stack Exchange sites that employ MathJax like the Mathematics Stack Exchange look like they have line breaks, but that's only because LaTeX has an included format that puts equaitons on their own line when enclosed by `$$`. [Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968574/how-to-prove-that-0-is-an-element-of-0-infinity#comment6127844_2968574). Outside of that, we don't have a way to do that, and Stack Overflow doesn't use MathJax.